# What is the difference between UserInfo session Id and Auth session Id?

Tags: apex, session, auth

I have come across these two ways to retrieve session Id in salesforce via Apex. I noticed Auth session Id not available in async or test classes but UserInfo session Id available all the time.

```
UserInfo.getSessionId();
```

And

```
Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().get('SessionId');
```

Which is the right way to refer to session Id to uniquely identify the salesforce session via Apex and limitations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserInfo.getSessionId()` should be the usual way to access the Session Id for a user. Please note, however, that even this method can return null:

> You can use `getSessionId()` both synchronously and asynchronously. In asynchronous Apex (Batch, Future, Queueable, or Scheduled Apex), this method returns the session ID only when the code is run by an active, valid user. When the code is run by an internal user, such as the automated process user or a proxy user, the method returns null.
>
> As a best practice, ensure that your code handles both cases: when a session ID is or is not available. [*documentation*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getSessionId)

`Auth.SessionManagement`'s Session Id is not available in some contexts:

> If you create an Apex test method that calls this method, the test fails with an error such as, “Unexpected Exception: Current session unavailable." An error occurs because there isn’t a session in the context through which the test is being run. [*documentation*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_SessionManagement.htm#apex_Auth_SessionManagement_getCurrentSession)

In other words, you must always be prepared for the possibility of a null session ID, and only UserInfo.getSessionId() is valid in unit tests. SessionManagement is useful for other cases, though, such as the LogoutUrl and other session parameters you might want access to.